# How to change IP in CentOS?

Tags: centos

My host has given me a new IP to use instead of the one I'm currently using. How can I set my server's IP from the old one to the new one?

Using CentOS 5.7, no control panels.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you have a static IP address.  Look in the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` directory.  You'll see files of the form `ifcfg-eth?`.  Depending on which interface you're changing, it'll be eth0, eth1, and so on.  Modify that file, then restart networking.

Comment: That was much easier than I thought it'd be! Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Just use the CLI menu command "setup"
Type that into bash and you'll get a menu that will do all the work ...